# Python unintuitive member variable behaviour

Tags: python, class, variables

This script:

```
class testa():
    a = []

class testb():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []

ta1 = testa(); ta1.a.append(1); ta2 = testa(); ta2.a.append(2)
tb1 = testb(); tb1.a.append(1); tb2 = testb(); tb2.a.append(2)

print ta1.a, ta2.a, tb1.a, tb2.a
```

produces this output:

```
[1, 2] [1, 2] [1] [2]
```

but I expected

```
[1] [2] [1] [2]
```

Why was I wrong? The definitions of testa and testb seem equivalent to me, so why should behavior change so drastically?!

**EDIT:** This seems unintuitive because it is different from how other types like int and str behave. For some reason lists are created as class variables when not initialized in **init**, but ints and strs are created as object variables no matter what.

Comment: The difference you see between strings, ints and lists is that lists are mutable but strings and ints are immutable. You can't change the value of a string. You can bind to a different string.

Comment: Strings and ints are also created as class variables. It's just you can't call `append` on an int, you have to rebind it with an assignment. This creates a **new** int object as an instance variable (unless you're rebinding it on the class), and leave the class variable hidden (for that particular instance) but intact.

Comment: Seems like we've gotten dozens of variants of this question recently...

Answer (score 7):

In `testa` the variable `a` is a *class variable* and is shared between all instances. `ta1.a` and `ta2.a` refer to the same list.

In `testb` the variable `a` is an *object variable*. Each instance has its own value.

See [Class and Object Variables](http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/class-and-object-vars.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

One is a class variable, the other is an instance variable.
Class vars are shared between all members of the class, instance vars are unique to each instance.
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 3):

It helps to remember that the `class` statement in Python is much closer to any other block statement than is the case for languages like C++.

In Python, a `class` statement contains a bunch of statements to be executed, just like `def`, `if`, or `while`. The difference is just in what the interpreter does with the block. In the case of flow control block statements like `if` and `while`, the interpreter executes the block as specified by the meaning of the flow control statement. In a `def`, the interpreter saves the block and executes it whenever the function object is called.

In the case of a `class` block, Python *executes the block immediately*, in a new scope, and then uses whatever is left in that scope after execution finishes as the contents of the class.

So for this:

```
class testa():
    a = []
```

Python executes the block `a = []`. Then at the end, the scope contains `a` bound to an empty list object. So that's what is in your **class**. Not any particular instance of the class, that is the class itself.

It inherits a do-nothing constructor from `object`, so that when you instantiate the class with `ta1 = testa()`, you get an empty instance. Then when you ask for `ta1.a`, Python finds no instance variable named `a` (because `ta1` has no instance variables at all), and so it looks for `a` in the class `testa`. This of course it finds; but it finds the same one for every instance of `testa`, and so you get the behaviour you observed.

On the other hand this:

```
class testb():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []
```

is completely different. Here once the class block has been executed the contents of the class scope is again a single name, but this time it's `__init__` bound to a function. That becomes the contents of the class.

Now when you instantiate **this** class with `testb()`, Python finds `__init__` in the class and calls that function with the new instance. The execution of that function creates an `a` *instance* variable in the new instance. So every instance of `testb()` gets its own variable, and you get the behaviour observed.

Take home message: a `class` block in Python is **not** just a set of declarations of things that are contained in instances of that class, unlike in traditional OO-ish languages like C++ and Java. It is actual code that is actually executed to define the contents of the class. This can be really handy: you can use if statements, the results of function execution, and anything you would use in any other context, inside your class body to decide what to define in your class.

(**NOTE**: I lied for simplicity earlier. Even instances of `testa` will have some instance variables, because there are some that are automatically created by default for all instances, but you don't see them as much in day-to-day Python).

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that classes **are** objects in Python. Reflection is built right in, no libraries required.

Answer (score 0):

> The definitions of testa and testb seem equivalent to me, so why should behavior change so drastically?!

Python's behaviour is completely logical - more so than that of Java or C++ or C#, in that **everything that you declare within the `class` scope belongs to the class.**

In Python, a class is logically a template for the objects, but it isn't really physically one. The closest you can get to specifying "instances have exactly this set of members" is to inherit from `object`, list them in the class' `__slots__` and initialize them in `__init__`. However, Python won't force you to set all the values in `__init__`, the ones you don't set don't get any default value (attempting to access them results in an `AttributeError`) and you can even explicitly remove attributes from instances later (via `del`). All that `__init__` does is run upon each new instance (which is a convenient and idiomatic way to set initial values for attributes). All that `__slots__` does is prevent adding **other** attributes.

> This seems unintuitive because it is different from how other types like int and str behave. For some reason lists are created as class variables when not initialized in init, but ints and strs are created as object variables no matter what.

This is not the case.

If you put an `int` or `str` there, it is still a member of the class. If you could somehow modify an `int` or `str`, then those changes would be reflected in every object, just as they are with the list, because looking up the attribute in the object would find it in the class. (Roughly speaking, attribute access checks the object first, then the class.)

However, you *can't actually do that*. What you think is an equivalent test isn't equivalent at all, because your test with an `int` or `str` causes an assignment to the object's attribute, which hides the class attribute. `ta1.a.append` calls a method of the list, which causes the list's internals to change. This is impossible for Python's strings and ints. Even if you write something like `ta1.n += 1`, this translates to `ta.n = ta.n + 1`, where the attribute is looked up (and found in the class), the sum calculated and then assigned back to `ta.n` (assignment will always update the object, unless explicitly forbidden by the class' `__slots__`, in which case an exception is raised).

You can trivially demonstrate that the value belongs to the class by *accessing it directly from the class*, e.g. `testa.a`.